# JTS Intersection

Tags: geotools, jts-topology-suite

I am testing the intersection method of JTS / GeoTools

I intersected 2 lines. Then I test if the intersection point intersects with one of the lines. The result should be true. But it is false if I use coordinates with many digits. I get true if I use coordinates with no digits.

Could anyone explain this to me?

```
GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();

double x1 = 10.342211513452, y1 = 11.342211514232, x2 = 0.342211513926, y2 = 1.342211513111,
            x3 = 0.342211513898, y3 = 13.342211513101, x4 = 11.342211513921, y4 = 2.342211513878;

//double x1 = 10, y1 = 11, x2 = 0, y2 = 1, x3 = 0, y3 = 13, x4 = 11, y4 = 2;

LineString line1 = gf.createLineString(new Coordinate[] { new Coordinate(x1, y1), new Coordinate(x2, y2) });
LineString line2 = gf.createLineString(new Coordinate[] { new Coordinate(x3, y3), new Coordinate(x4, y4) });
Point intersectionPoint = (Point) line2.intersection(line1);

System.out.println(line1.intersects(intersectionPoint)); // true for no digits, false for many digits
System.out.println(line2.intersects(intersectionPoint)); // true for no digits, false for many digits
```

Comment: You asked about the precision model in another question. I suppose that this problem has to do with precision as well.

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates of the calculated intersection point are more accurate than the other coordinates. This is why the intersection result is not true. A workaround is to use a very small buffer:

```
GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();

double x1 = 10.342211513452, y1 = 11.342211514232, x2 = 0.342211513926, y2 = 1.342211513111,
            x3 = 0.342211513898, y3 = 13.342211513101, x4 = 11.342211513921, y4 = 2.342211513878;

LineString line1 = gf.createLineString(new Coordinate[] { new Coordinate(x1, y1), new Coordinate(x2, y2) });
LineString line2 = gf.createLineString(new Coordinate[] { new Coordinate(x3, y3), new Coordinate(x4, y4) });
Point intersectionPoint = (Point) line2.intersection(line1);

// define very small buffer
double bufferDistance = 0.0001 * 0.0001 * 0.0001;
// use buffer when looking for intersection
System.out.println(line1.buffer(bufferDistance).intersects(intersectionPoint)); // true
System.out.println(line2.buffer(bufferDistance).intersects(intersectionPoint)); // true
```